# Write formulas to Excel cell using VBA variables instead of a long string representing the formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I typically write formulas from VBA to Excel cells using the following method:

```
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = "=SUMIF('6. Calculation sheet'!A:A,C48,'6. Calculation sheet'!J:J)"
```

Is there an alternative way to similarly write a formula to a range of cells but to use more VBA variables and fewer strings?

Something like

```
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = Application.Worksheetfunction.Sumif(wksActual.Range("A:A"), wksActual.Range("C48"), wksActual.Range("J:J"))
```

Comment: The `Application.Worksheetfunction.Sumif` function will actually try to calculate its results before making the Formula on the range equal to it. This is not likely what you want. In your first example though as you are writing the formula in as a string you can manipulate that string with variables. So you could do `wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = "=SUMIF(" & CustomRange1.Address & ", " & CustomRange2.Address & ", " & CustomRange3.Address & ")"` Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: @nbayly - why not write that as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: I guess I could have. Though I was just planning on giving a general counsel on how to proceed I guess I ended up being fairly specific. Anyways, your answer provided gave more thorough details than I was planning. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically writing formulas in excel, most of the time, is about filling the function's parameters with addresses. These addresses only need an External Reference when they are referring to a range outside of the worksheet where the formula is entered.

OP's sample formulas are referring to the same worksheet in which they will be written

```
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = "=SUMIF('6. Calculation sheet'!A:A,C48,'6. Calculation sheet'!J:J)"
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(wksActual.Range("A:A"), wksActual.Range("C48"), wksActual.Range("J:J"))
```

*(with the issue on the Application.WorksheetFunction very well explained by  @ChipsLetten let’s concentrate on the excel formula)*

Therefore the formula above can be written as follows:

```
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = "=SUMIF(A:A,C48,J:J)"
```

or

```
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = "=SUMIF($A:$A,$C48,$J:$J)"
```

Now, if you really want to use variables to write this formula, I will suggest to create string variables like:

```
sRngTrg = "D48:D52"
sFmlRng = "$A:$A”
sFmlCri1 = "$C48"
sFmlRsm1 = "$J:$J"
```

then the formula will be

```
wksActual.Range(sRngTrg).Formula = _
    "=SUMIF(" & sFmlRng & "," & sFmlCri1 & "," & sFmlRsm1 & ")"
```

The above would be practical and efficient if these ranges are used several times in the code, in which case it will be more practical to create range variables like

```
With wksActual
    Set rRngTrg = .Range("D48:D52")
    Set rFmlRng = .Range("$A:$A")
    Set rFmlCri1 = .Range("$C48")
    Set rFmlRsm1 = .Range("$J:$J")
End With
```

the formula should be

```
rRngTrg.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & rFmlRng.Address & "," & _
    rFmlCri1.Address(0) & "," & rFmlRsm1.Address & ")"
```

If the formula refers to another workbook or worksheet and we are using a range variable.
*`rOthFmlRng` and `rOthFmlRsm1` are ranges from another worksheet in the same workbook*

```
With wksOther
    Set rOthFmlRng = .Range("$A:$A")
    Set rOthFmlRsm1 = .Range("$J:$J")
End With
```

Just need to add the External parameter to the Address of the range as below:

```
rRngTrg.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & rOthFmlRng.Address(External:=1) & "," & _
    rFmlCri1.Address(0) & "," & rOthFmlRsm1.Address(External:=1) & ")"
```

*`rExtWbkRng` and `rExtWbkRsm1` are ranges from a worksheet in another workbook*

```
With Workbooks("Book Open.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    Set rExtWbkRng = .Range("$A:$A")
    Set rExtWbkRsm1 = .Range("$J:$J")
End With
```

same as before

```
rRngTrg.Formula = "=SUMIF(" & rExtWbkRng.Address(External:=1) & "," & _
    rFmlCri1.Address(0) & "," & rExtWbkRsm1.Address(External:=1) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two vba techniques you'd need to know to do it similarly to what you just did are the Range.Address property and concatenation using &.

I am not sure how much time or space it would save you, but if you prefer using vba variables to worksheet ranges, that would work.

You can read more on Range.Address here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx

You can read more on concatenation here:
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat2.php

Answer (score 0):

The `Application.WorksheetFunction` object is for using the Excel functions within VBA code so that your code can then use the result. If you want to use ranges rather than strings to build an Excel formula you need to use the actual function name as a string but then append the range addresses. You need to be careful of absolute versus relative cell addresses. Your example would become:

```
wksActual.Range("D48:D52").Formula = "=SUMIF(" & wksActual.Range("A:A").Address & ", " & wksActual.Range("C48").Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ", " & wksActual.Range("J:J").Address & ")"
```

The `RowAbsolute:=False` parameter is needed because otherwise each cell in `D48:D52` is looking at cell $C$48.

If you need to reference a range on another sheet, use the `External:=True` parameter of the `Address` property so that the sheet name is included. Otherwise you'll need to add `"sheet_name"!` before the range address.

You can also look at using R1C1 addressing style for some functions using the `FormulaR1C1` property.